# Could we tell whether two matrices are congruent only by its eigenvalues? if not, How many conditions do we need?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices, matrix-congruences

When I was learning in my junior high, I am  fascinated by the fact that There are more than one way like SSS, SAS etc to tell whether two triangles are congruent or not. Thus I am wondering, Is there a similar criterion for matrices?
That is to say, How much  conditions is enough to say two  matrices is congruent? Is there a theorem of it? If there is, may you tell me the reference? And moreover, Is there a similar theorem for the criterion of similar matrices?
Thank you for any advices

Comment: If each eigenvalue has the same algebraic multiplicity and the same geometric multiplicity in both matrices, then the matrices should be similar.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang: this is not true, it's not enough information to recover the sizes of the Jordan blocks.

Comment: @Tong: the eigenvalues are not enough even with multiplicities. You want to look up Jordan normal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: In the title, you want the matrices to be similar/congruent (which are two different things), in the body you want to "define" the matrix (by which I assume you mean, to specify it uniquely), so you are asking three different questions. This places a burden on anyone who tries to help you.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I am extremely sorry sir, I am just trying to use my bare knowledge of the congruence and similarity of triangles to imagine similar relation of matrices. I have already edited my questions and contents to be more specific ,  is that satisified enough? if not , is there anything more I can do with it to make my question more clear?

Comment: The question is fine now.